# I'm writing a SHMOOP and I'm trying to grab the correct frame in the image strip by multiplying currentFrame index by frame width

Tags: c#

So the title pretty much sums up my question, so here's the code:

```
destinationRect = new Rectangle((int)Position.X = (int)(FrameWidth * scale) / 2,
                 (int)Position.Y - (int)(FrameHeight * scale) / 2,
                 (int)(FrameWidth * scale),
                 (int)(FrameHeight * scale));
```

but for whatever reason it is underlining the very first `int`, the one in this code: `(int)Position.X`,  in red and saying

> The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property, or indexer.

Can someone please tell me what I can do to fix this?

Comment: can you tell me what are you trying to do here ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a typo, and used `=` instead of `-`?

```
new Rectangle(
    (int)Position.X - (int)(FrameWidth * scale) / 2,
    (int)Position.Y - (int)(FrameHeight * scale) / 2,
    (int)(FrameWidth * scale),
    (int)(FrameHeight * scale));
```

Comment: Where were my eyes?! You are right! +1